# how to send a Stream from flutter to ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart

I am working on a ios app i want to use an sdk that i wrote with flutter, where I have a scan method that returns a Stream<List>. I want to call this scan method from my native Swift code, then receive and handle the Stream<List> in Swift.

I am tried using a MethodChannel in Flutter to handle the call from Swift and start the scan, and the method handler returns the Stream<List>. However, I am unsure how to send this stream to Swift and handle it there.

here is the relevant part of my Flutter code:

```
const methodChannel = MethodChannel('com.example/my_method_channel');

Future<Stream<List<FoundDevice>>> methodHandler(MethodCall call) {
  final String idea = call.arguments;

  switch (call.method) {
    case "scan":
      return _handleScanCall();

    default:
      print('no method handler for method ${call.method}');
      throw MissingPluginException();
  }
}

Future<Stream<List<FoundDevice>>> _handleScanCall() async {
  print('scan called from iOS native code');
  return TrackbarSDK.instance.scan();
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(methodHandler);
}
```

And here is my current Swift code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var methodChannel: FlutterMethodChannel?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    methodChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example/my_method_channel", binaryMessenger: appDelegate.flutterEngine.binaryMessenger)
    
    startScan()
  }
  
  func startScan() {
    methodChannel?.invokeMethod("scan", arguments: nil, result: { (result: Any?) in
      // This is where I want to receive and handle the Stream<List<FoundDevice>>
    })
  }
}
```

My question is: How can I send a Stream<List> from Flutter to Swift, and then listen to and handle this stream in the Swift code?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you cannot send a `Stream` - you can only send it's data, do that by calling `listen()` method on that stream and inside the callback send the data via `MethodChannel`

Comment: do you know if that Would be performant enough, and is FIFO guarnteed? 
I found a few articls saying that the eventChannel is the way to go, and that it's bidirectional but i can't find any methods on the class to send data from the flutter side. Thanks in advance

Comment: use `setMethodCallHandler`: https://api.flutter.dev/objcdoc/Classes/FlutterMethodChannel.html#/c:objc(cs)FlutterMethodChannel(im)setMethodCallHandler: the docs say: "Registers a handler for method calls from the Flutter side.

Replaces any existing handler. Use a nil handler for unregistering the existing handler."

Comment: thank that's what i'm trying right now it seems to be doing the job.

Comment: btw there is a way of getting a `Stream` from Swift side but I couldn't find an opposite way, see `EventChannel` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/EventChannel/receiveBroadcastStream.html

Comment: btw 2, you could also use message channel as you don't really need 2 way communication channel, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/BasicMessageChannel-class.html - in theory it should be faster

Comment: yes I'm using the method channel right now but I'll also try it with the message channel next

Comment: i need two way communication but i can use two channels one to send commands to flutter and the other to receive data from the in the native side